# Getting an error: "Extensions may not contain stored properties"

Tags: swift

I am new in Swift and xcode. I am trying to declare a GoogleMobileAds variable inside a `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`, but I am getting an error: Extensions may not contain stored properties.

Here is my code:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

extension MainBiblePagerVC: UISplitViewControllerDelegate{
    // Setup Navigation Items in Bible Page
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you reviewed [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Extensions+may+not+contain+stored+properties) on the error?

Comment: And you should read the [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) chapter of the Swift book.

Comment: Try to understand error messages. This one is crystal clear: `interstitial` is a stored property and *Extensions may not contain stored properties*.

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare stored properties inside extension, only computed ones

So you have two ways:

1. declare stored property inside your class MainBiblePagerVC
2. use computed property:

   ```
   extension MainBiblePagerVC: UISplitViewControllerDelegate{
       var interstitial: GADInterstitial! {
           // add object initialization here
           let object = GADInterstitial()
           // set its parameters 
           return object
       }
   }
   ```